# error while browse phone using Bluetooth

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

i recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and connect my Nokia phone from "Bluetooth Menu -> Setup new device". when i click on "Browse files" a new window popup and show my phone contents but i can't copy any file from phone or phone memory to my computer.

Error Message:

> Error while copying “rec56.mp3”.
>
> There was an error copying the file into /home/homepc/Desktop.
>
> Another operation in progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bumped into a known issue, it has been reported in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1284308, and many other people also have the same issue. As a workaround, try sending the files from the phone to the computer, or use a USB cable to do the file transfer.

Comment: thank you for reply
is there any software for bluetooth device browser and data transfer ?

Comment: are you asking for bluetooth software on the phone or Ubuntu? If for Ubuntu, you don't need to specifically install anything, the bluetooth stack is installed by default. For phone, it really depends on what OS the phone is using.

Comment: See comments #50 and #51 in the bug referenced for a workaround.